# Prolog library to link with gcc

Tags: prolog, ffi

Could you recommend a Prolog implementation featuring interpreter library which could be linked to C program built with gcc like Lua or Squirrel?

Comment: Essentially all systems have one interface or another, your question will stir up a lot of discussions about who likes which system. [Here](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Mixing-C-and-Prolog.html) is the interface of SICStus Prolog to mix C, C++ and Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

Some Prolog systems can be compiled as a dynamic library for linking with other libraries. An example is YAP:

http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog is  built in ANSI-C as a shared library, and has *extensive* [C](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=foreign) and [C++](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/pl2cpp.html%27%29) interfaces.

Also [GNU Prolog](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/) offers a sophisticated C interface, with optional compilation of Prolog code to native C.